# Fork in perl but get exit status from a system call in the child process

Tags: ajax, perl, fork, exit, qx

### What I do:

1. Make an ajax call to a cgi script.
2. Cgi script forks but the parent returns right away with a response msg.
3. The child does a system call but needs the exit code and any error messages.

### Pseudo-code:

```
$SIG{CHLD} = ‘IGNORE’; # or waitpid($pid,0) in the parent process
$pid = fork();
if($pid == 0)
{
    close STDOUT; # So that the parent sends the response to the client right away.

    @errorMsgs = qx(tar up big directories over 50G…); # This can go on for a few minutes.

    if($? ==0) { Send a ‘success’ email } # Is always false ($? == -1)

    else { Send a ‘failure’ email }
}
elsif($pid){ sendResponse; waitpid($pid,0) if $SIG{CHLD} != 'IGNORE'; exit;}
```

### My problem:

Trouble getting a correct return code ($?) and any error messages from qx() as it is set to -1 due to ($SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'). If I remove $SIG{CHLD} statement, the client web page does not receive a response msg from the parent until after the child is reaped.

Comment: Maybe the parent output is buffered. What happens if you forget the SIGCHLD handler and just make sure you set `$| = 1` ?

Comment: @mob: It's on Linux. I am able to send the response by setting $| but I read it's a bad practice to not wait for children and it might lead to zombies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a -1 because you're setting `$SIG{CHLD}` to `IGNORE`.  By doing that, you're killing `qx`'s ability to capture the exit code of `tar`... it will die without notifying the parent (your child process).

It's simple enough to test out:

```
perl -e '$SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE"; system("ps"); print "Finished with $?\n";
```

This gives -1.

```
perl -e 'system("ps"); print "Finished with $?\n";
```

This gives 0.

If you really need the `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'`, then just `$SIG{CHLD} = 'DEFAULT'` before your `qx` call.

Also, make sure you're using the full path to `tar` (e.g. `/bin/tar`) just in case you don't have `/bin` in your path, and it's failing to execute.  However, I'm assuming that's OK since you didn't say anything about your tar file not being created.

Comment: Yes, tar works ok with its full path. Setting $SIG{CHLD} to undef solved it. The reason I set $SIG{CHLD} to IGNORE is to avoid creating zombies. But this fixed it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you reset `$SIG{CHLD}` to `undef` in the child section (i.e. after `$pid == 0`), it won't affect the parent process, right?

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot ! Mark's statement above - "By doing that, you're killing qx's ability to capture the exit code of tar... it will die without notifying the parent (your child process)." - pretty much explains what's going on. The child loses its ability to return any status to its parent.